# How to use if-else statement within while loop in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I've got some problems when comparing two variables in my CSV

here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < /path/to/file/PARAM.csv || exit 1
read header # read (and ignore) the first line
while IFS=, read table column; do
    if [[ $column = "NULL" ]]; then
        echo "empty"
    else
        echo $column
    fi
done
```

in my file there are some fields that have `"NULL"` values, but the comparison isn't working, it always print the `$column`

Here is some example in my CSV :

```
MAIN_RPT_STD010,NULL
MAIN_RPT_STD030,NULL
MAIN_RPT_STD050,NULL
MAIN_RPT_STD070,NULL
MAIN_RPT_STD090,NULL
MAIN_ACTIVO,BUSS_DATE
MAIN_ACTUAL_SCORECARD,BUSS_DATE
```

Comment: Add some sample input to the question.

Comment: @Barmar there are some changes

Comment: Make sure the file doesn't have Windows CRLF line endings.

Comment: Try wildcard `if [[ "$column" == *NULL* ]];`

Comment: Your script works fine for me. I'll bet there's either a space or CR after `NULL`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks man, that was a CRLF problem. you saved my life